# Check Printing With EC13B Font in PDFLaTeX

Tags: fonts

I have made a template for printing checks from blank check stock but I am stuck on printing the [MICR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) E-13B font at the bottom. I have found the true type font [here](http://www.sandeen.net/GnuMICR/). I am using PDFLaTeX but can't seem to find any information on specifying a font with anything other than XeLaTeX. Is this possible with PDFLaTeX?

The numbers at the base of the check are mostly static (account and routing number) but the check number is dynamic so that rules out a work around of simply positioning a pre-made EPS.

Comment: Why is XeLTeX a problem for you? It is the easiest way to use fonts. LuaLaTeX would be another option, and I think it can use `pdflatex`. In either case, just load `fontspec` and specify `\setmainfont{}` with the name of your font, as it appears in your computer's softwares, scrolldown, etc. (not the file name).

Comment: I suppose I don't *really* have a good reason not to use LuaLaTex. It's just that I am currently using pdf2tex on an ancient Ubuntu install. That seems to be a rather easy solution and probably worth downloading TeXworks and using Windows.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use pdfLaTeX. However, you would have to create all of the support files pdfLaTeX needds to use the font. pdfTeX can use truetype fonts if they are reencoded but it needs all of the support files required by LaTeX (`.tfm`, `.map`, `.fd`, maybe `.enc`, maybe `.vf`). That is doable but it is not straightforward. Xe/LuaLaTeX are better options.

Comment: Aren't the `ocra`, `ocrb` or [`ocr-b-outline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ocr-b-outline) packages an option for you?

Comment: @Malipivo I don't see the E-13B font in any of those packages. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you don't, it was an idea if those fonts could serve as a substitute to E-13B. I was mistaken.

Comment: would you mind sharing your template please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fond memories of those font conversion times... I have downloaded and unzipped the [ZIP file](http://www.sandeen.net/GnuMICR/download/GnuMICR-0.30.zip) into my working directory and I ran (I'm sorry, I haven't polished the `8r.enc` file from the TeX distribution in any way, so there are some warning messages about missing letters):

> afm2tfm GnuMICR.afm GnuMICR.tfm
>   pdflatex mal-ec13B.tex

The main TeX file looks like this:

```
%! pdflatex mal-ec13B.tex
\pdfmapline{+GnuMICR GnuMICR <8r.enc <GnuMICR.ttf}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\font\malfont=GnuMICR % setting the font
Text before {\malfont % loading the font
A B 12345 67890 C D} text after. % using the font
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]